# trigger sublime snippets on cmd+space instead of cmd+tab

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets, sublimetext3

by default it is cmd+tab,

can I make it cmd+space???

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
console.log(${1:});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>con</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Comment: `Cmd+Tab` switches windows in OS X, it has nothing to do with Sublime. The default key for autocomplete is `Ctrl+Space`, not `Cmd+Space`.

Comment: I'm not talking about autocomplete. I meant code snippets.